# How to retrieve result of a query in variables with the same name of fields?

Tags: php, sql, variables, syntax

I'm looking for a php syntax which allows, after a sql query like :

```
$query = "SELECT module, operation FROM webfolders";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$typeContenu = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

To recover the result in a variable with the same name as the desired field.

For my example, i don't want `$typeContenu['module']` or `$typeContenu['operation ']` but directly `$module` and `$operation`.

I think for do this, there is a "@" to put somewhere...i don't remember.

Do you undestand what i want ? Thanks !

Comment: use extract(), but you could use an objective way to do it, like so $typeContenu->module

Comment: Don't do that. It's pretty ugly. *Especially* when you start using it with `SELECT *` queries later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don`t u use http://php.net/extract - Import variables into the current symbol table from an array, but try to avoid it becouse it can get confusing

Comment: if he uses a smart prefix with extract there can't be any confusion and collisions

Comment: Confusion as in...all of the sudden you see an undeclared variable while reading someone's code...in a big project it is bad practice...

Comment: well, naturally that is to be expected if you use something like explode....

Answer (score 1):

Try using [list()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php):

```
$query = "SELECT module, operation FROM webfolders";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$typeContenu = mysql_fetch_array($result);

list($module, $operation) = $typeContenu;
```

You will have to define the variable names but this way you have more control and can set whatever simple variable name you want, and it's more secure than extract().

Make sure to input in `list()` in the same order you set the column fields in the SQL query.